# How to run function passed as prop inside child's function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

as in title - in parent component I pass function as prop to child and I'd like to run this function inside child component, but in child's function.

```
//parent component
<div>
    <Child myFunction={this.myFunction} />
</div>
```

and in child component I create new function

```
//child component
    newFunction = () => {
        //someNewCode
        this.props.myFunction();
    }
    <button onClick={this.newFunction}>click me</button>
```

but it's not working. Where's the problem?

Comment: What exactly isn't working? That's exactly how you use it. Is the code just not running? Can you throw a log statement in parent's function?

Answer (score 4):

The following should work.

Perhaps `this.myFunction` isn't an arrow function and you forgot to bind it.

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {

  myFunction = () => {
    console.log("Luke, I am your father");
  };

  render() {
    return <Child myFunction={this.myFunction} />;
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {

  newFunction = () => {
    this.props.myFunction();
  }

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.newFunction}>click me</button>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
```